# Maximize/force confirm Reflex save

Tags: dnd-3.5e, optimization, saving-throw

I'm looking for a way for my Rogue-like character to maximize or at best have the ability to auto-confirm at least one Reflex save per day. He's level 15 at the moment (it's a multiclass character) and his Reflex save can reach pretty high amounts along with party buffs (28 in the last battle).

The goal is however to have the ability to confirm very high Reflex DCs (in the range of 60 at the moment) which seems only possible with forcing a natural 20 roll or with some kind of ability that allows for an auto-confirmed Reflex save check.

I know of Surge of Fortune (Cleric 5th level) spell that provides such an effect but I haven't found any way to cast it on myself yet (and no one else can cast it on me since it's a Range: Personal spell...) and I would prefer it not to be dispellable.

Comment: To confrm my understanding is the question *Other than the* surge of fortune *spell, how can I get I guarantee a 20 on a Reflex saving throw?* or is it *How can I improve my already ridiculous Reflex saving throw?* or is it the stealth question *How can my rogue consistently employ the* surge of fortune *spell?*

Comment: Improving my already ridiculous saving throw might be impossible so maybe finding a way to auto succeed other than with Surge of Fortune (preferably with a bigger usage timeframe/less anticipation)

Answer (score 3):

#### Use Magic Device skill with a scroll/staff of *surge of fortune*

[Use Magic Device](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/useMagicDevice.htm) is a skill available to a rogue, and a 15th level rogue can trivially have a +20 or higher bonus to that skill.

The DC to use a wand or staff of *surge of fortune* (a somewhat expensive item, but within the finances of a 15th level character) as if you were a cleric is only DC 20, so you can easily auto-succeed.

Comment: Are you sure about staves? Although I haven't confirmed it, the DM said the DC should be much higher than 20

Comment: Use Magic Device's "Use a wand" feature says: "This use of the skill also applies to other spell trigger magic items, such as staffs." A scroll's DC is higher (20 + caster level), but the wand DC is only 20.

Answer (score 0):

You could commission a magic item capable of producing a *surge of fortune* on you once a day.  As there are no body slots with a luck affinity, you would probably have to make it either a robe (affinity: multiple effects, and *surge of fortune* certainly effects a lot of different types of rolls) or a ring (to not have to worry about affinity), but your DM might allow you to make it as boots (affinity: movement) based on the flavor text of the spell indicating "*guiding your movements*", but I wouldn't count on it.

If your DM goes with estimated gp value, the item should cost 9 (caster level) * 5 (spell level) * 2,000 gp / 5 (1 charge a day cost reduction) = 18,000 gp.  This is only slightly more expensive than a spell trigger item (which would be 16,875 gp, *i.e.* 375 gp rather than 400 gp * caster and spell levels), avoids the need of Use Magic Device, and will not eventually permanently run out of charges.  As an option, however, the cost could be increased to 27,000 gp to make it as a non-affinity body slot item, or 36,000 gp to make it as an item that doesn't use up a body slot at all.

As a further consideration, as the auto-20 seems to be your primary concern, if you had the item enchanted such that it only provided that portion of the spell effect (and not the +2 to rolls for 1 round/caster level), you might be able to have the item activation be an immediate action, so you wouldn't have to activate the item in advance and then hope you needed the effect within 9 rounds.  That way you'd be a whole lot less likely to waste your 1 charge a day.